# ssh does not return when executing remote process in bg

Tags: ssh, remote, ssh-tunneling, background-process

I'm trying to open a tunnel on a remote server from local machine by executing a command remotely via ssh. I'm using sshpass too.

```
sshpass -fpw_file.txt ssh user@host.com 'bash /home/username/do_stuff.sh &'
```

This do_stuff.sh contains just one line:

```
ssh -f -N -L 8888:hostname:9999 user@host &
```

But the call (first command) is not returning. If I put & outside the single quotes, it spawns a process which is not getting killed. Although it is a very small memory leak, it would be good to know if there is a way to do this cleanly.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the i/o streams to null? `sshpass -fpw_file.txt ssh user@host.com 'bash /home/username/do_stuff.sh &> /dev/null < /dev/null &'` [ssh won't exit until all streams are closed](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html).

Comment: That worked for me! Thanks! I would love to know details of the last part. I understand that we're redirecting output of 'bash /path/to/file.sh' to /dev/null. But what is '< /dev/null &' doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the i/o streams to null. [BG processes with open descriptors can cause SSH to not close](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html).

```
sshpass -fpw_file.txt ssh user@host.com 'bash /home/username/do_stuff.sh &> /dev/null < /dev/null &'
```

Explanation

`&> /dev/null` takes stdout and stderr and redirects it to null

`< /dev/null` takes stdin and redirects it to null

`&` at the end sends the process to the background.

Comment: Nice.  So many people have asked this and the first real answer.